# SreamProvider containing specific documents

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I have a streamProvider that contains all of the documents from a collection.

I want a StreamProvider that contains only certain documents. Can I use .where('agency', isEqualTo: 'some name'? Can this be done and if so how do I do it? Below is my current code:

'''

```
// From the main.dart 
return MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        StreamProvider(create: (context) => firestoreService.getTrxns()),
      ],
      child: MaterialApp(
        initialRoute: WelcomeScreen.id,
        routes: {
          WelcomeScreen.id: (context) => WelcomeScreen(),
          Home_Screen.id: (context) => Home_Screen(),

        },

/// This is from a Services.dart file
  Stream<List<Trxns>> getTrxns() {
    return _db.collection('trxns').snapshots().map((snapshot) => snapshot.docs
        .map((document) => Trxns.fromFirestore(document.data()))
        .toList());
  }
```

'''

Answer (score 1):

That's exactly how you would do it:

```
  _db.collection('trxns').where('agency', isEqualTo: 
     'some name').snapshots().map()
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have tried it but I am getting an error.  return  _db.collection('trxns').snapshots().where('agency', isEqualTo: globals.agentAgencyName).map((snapshot) => snapshot.docs
        .map((document) => Trxns.fromFirestore(document.data()))
        .toList());

Comment: The error I get on the where('agency', isEqualTo: code is "The argument type String can't be assigned to the parameter type 'bool Function(QuerySnapshot)'. So the QuerySnapshot won't work here. Is there something else I can use?

Comment: I swapped the where and snapshots.  Check out the updated answer.